# Rules of "Constellations" (1984)

Tags: constellations-petra-press

I played a Halley's Comet themed game in 1984 that was called Constellations. I've only been able to find it on Ebay so far: https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Vintage-Game-Circa-1984-Constellations-Darryl-Hemsley-Adelaide-Basket-Range-/382983024814. I can't find it on Board Game Geek.

[image]

You had to collect three pieces of a comet, the "head", the "body", and the "tail". Each piece was a square piece of cardboard, with a third of a comet on one side and various "constellations" (squares or lines of four stars) on the other side. There was much more to the game than that, but that's all I can remember.

[image]

How can I find the complete rules?

Comment: The creator of the game seems to have a LinkedIn profile

Answer (score 3):

A librarian at the University of South Australia was able to help me get an image of the rules sheet. (Well, for the self-published 1982 edition, the one with the white box, not the Petra Press edition with the black box).

It is a version of 4x4 tic-tac-toe ("noughts and crosses" on the game description), but with the connection matrix of the board determined by magic square number sums (and these connections are indicated as "constellations" around the board, for easier figuring).

Players take turns playing to squares, trying to be the first to make a four-star constellation (having four squares that sum to 34). For this, they take the card matching the constellation made. Each card shows the number of points it is worth.

The game continues (resets), with the loser of the round starting the next round, until the a constellation made matches the top card of the deck (unseen; it is only checked when a constellation is made).

Most cards and highest points wins. (The rules sheet is vague on the what happens when one player has the most cards but the other player has the most points; I assume this was corrected in the Petra Press edition to just be "most points").

[image: Rules sheet of the game Constellations by D. J. Hemsley]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your game. It has the same name and year of publish however a different box. See [Link](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/CONSTELLATION-Rare-board-game-by-Helmut-Kempel-1984-2-Complete-Copies-/273116244648)

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, that's definitely not it. You can see the constellation cards in my link to Ebay. There are pegs, so it might have something to do with filling a 4x4 board?